# Github actions Workflow not running when opening a Pull Request

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have the following trigger

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
    branches:
      - 'foobranch'
  issue_comment:
    types:
      - created
```

When opening a PR targeting `foobranch`, the workflow **does not run**.

Is it because the workflow file does not exist on any other branch than the default? (`master`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GitHub uses the sources of the associated pull request so you most likely need to rebase the branch or cherry-pick the workflow to your pull request branch.

GitHub documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#about-workflow-triggers):

> GitHub searches the .github/workflows directory in your repository for workflow files that are present in the associated commit SHA or Git ref of the event.